# Search Script for PHP website with MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a PHP website to display products. I need to introduce a 'Search' feature whereby a keyword or phrase can be found among number of products.

I went through number of existing scripts and wrote/modified one for me which though able to connect to database, doesn't return any value. The debug mode throws a warning "  `mysqli_num_rows()` expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given ". Seems I am not collecting the query value correctly. The PHP Manuals says that `mysqli_query()` returns FALSE on failure and for successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries `mysqli_query()` will return a `mysqli_result` object and for other successful queries `mysqli_query()` will return TRUE ".

Any suggestions?

```
<form name="search" method="post" action="search.php">
        <input type="text" name="searchterm" />
        <input type="hidden" name="searching" value="yes" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>

    <?php 
     $searchterm=trim($_POST['searchterm']);
     $searching = $_POST['searching'];
     $search = $_POST['search'];

     //This is only displayed if they have submitted the form 
     if ($searching =="yes") 
     {
        echo 'Results'; 

         //If they forget to enter a search term display an error 
         if (!$searchterm) 
         { 
            echo 'You forgot to enter a search term'; 
            exit; 
         } 

         //Filter the user input
         if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
            $searchterm = addslashes($searchterm);

         // Now connect to Database 
         @ $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','username','password','database' );

         if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo 'Error: Could not connect to the database. Please try again later.';
            exit;
         }
         else {
             echo "Database connection successful."; //Check to see whether we have connected to database at all!
         }
         //Query the database
         $query = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%$searchterm%' OR post_excerpt LIKE '%$searchterm%' OR post_content LIKE '%$searchterm%'";
         $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

         if (!$result)
            echo "No result found";

         $num_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);

         echo "<p>Number of match found: ".$num_results."</p>";

        foreach ($result as $searchResult) {
            print_r($searchResult);
        }

        echo "You searched for $searchterm";

        $result->free();
        $db->close();
     }
```

Comment: Corrected the code for errors as pointed out by @Rasclatt .

Comment: No, it didn't. As explained above, seems I am unable to collect the return object/value correctly in `mysqli_query()` function.

Comment: Yeah I just read that. When I have a moment I will solve it, provided no one else has by the time I am able to look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be something like `'%$searchterm%'`, not `'%{searchterm}%'` in your query. You are not searching for your variable `$searchterm` in your example.

Google's display uses `LIMIT` in the query so it only displays a certain amount of results at a time (known as [pagination](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-paginate-data-with-php--net-2928)).

This is tested and works. You will need to change 1) db connection info in the search engine class. 2) If you want it to be on separate pages, you will have to split it up. If not, copy this whole code to one page and it will work on that one page.

```
<?php
    class DBEngine
        {
            protected   $con;
            // Create a default database element
            public  function __construct($host = '',$db = '',$user = '',$pass = '')
                {
                    try {
                            $this->con  =   new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db",$user,$pass, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));
                        }
                    catch (Exception $e) {
                          return 0;
                        }
                }

            // Simple fetch and return method
            public  function Fetch($_sql)
                {
                    $query  =   $this->con->prepare($_sql);
                    $query->execute();

                    if($query->rowCount() > 0) {
                            $rows   =   $query->fetchAll();
                        }

                    return (isset($rows) && $rows !== 0 && !empty($rows))? $rows: 0;
                }

            // Simple write to db method
            public  function Write($_sql)
                {
                    $query  =   $this->con->prepare($_sql);
                    $query->execute();
                }
        }

    class   SearchEngine
        {
            protected   $searchterm;
            public  function execute($searchword)
                {
                    $this->searchterm   =   htmlentities(trim($searchword), ENT_QUOTES);
                }

            public  function display()
                { ?>
                    <h1>Results</h1>
                <?php 

                    //If they forget to enter a search term display an error 
                    if(empty($this->searchterm)) { ?>
                    <h3>Search Empty</h3>
                    <p>You must fill out search field.</p>
                    <?php }
                    else {
                            $con        =    new DBEngine('localhost','database','username','password');
                            $results    =   $con->Fetch( "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%".$this->searchterm."%' OR post_excerpt LIKE '%".$this->searchterm."%' OR post_content LIKE '%".$this->searchterm."%'");

                            if($results !== 0 && !empty($results)) { ?>
                                    <p>Number of match found: <?php echo count($results); ?> on search:<br />
                                    <?php echo strip_tags(html_entity_decode($this->searchterm)); ?></p>
                                    <?php
                                    foreach($results as $rows) {
                                            echo '<pre>';
                                            print_r($rows);
                                            echo '</pre>';
                                        }
                                }
                            else { ?>
                                    <h3>No results found.</h3>
                                    <?php
                                }
                        }
                }
        }

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $searcher   =   new SearchEngine();
            $searcher->execute($_POST['searchterm']);
            $searcher->display();
        } ?>
    <form name="search" method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" name="searchterm" />
        <input type="hidden" name="searching" value="yes" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
```

Comment: @Rascallat Good observation. Changed it to `'%$searchterm%'`. But didn't help. Is query structure correct?

Comment: It looks correct. Does it just say 0 rows returned?

Comment: No. For number of results found, it renders a blank.

Comment: Debug says `mysqli_num_rows()` expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given.

Answer (score 0):

To do your literal search as you have it, you would need to change the code `'%{searchterm}%'` to `'%$searchterm%'`, since [the brackets aren't needed](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html) and you were searching for the phrase *"{searchterm}."* Outside of that you might want to take a look at [FULLTEXT search capabilities](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html) since you're doing a literal search in your current method.

To make the output look like Google's output you would simply code a wrapper for each search result and style them with CSS and HTML.